# Bing Voice Recognition API Output - Number vs Text

Tags: azure, voice-recognition

I'm seeing some odd behavior where the voice recognition API will sometimes return words and sometimes return numbers.  For example, given the audio input of "fifteen dollars and seven cents" it will sometimes return "fifteen dollars and seven cents" and others "$15.07".  Is there a way to ensure one or the other are returned?  Or, will I need to parse and convert words to numbers on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: There is already such a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325602/getting-different-results-via-bing-speech-recognition-api-beta-for-same-audio

Answer (score 1):

i just looked into similar issues, and found that BingSTT API returns both versions in different fields. Just tried your example with the example code from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-JavaScript and got this response:

```
[{
"lexical": "fifteen dollars and seven cents",
"display": "$15.07.",
"inverseNormalization": null,
"maskedInverseNormalization": null,
"transcript": "$15.07.",
"confidence": 0.9474185
}]
```

So i guess the choice is yours which field to use, lexical or the display. Hope this helps.